# How to define custom compile commands in auctex?

Tags: auctex, shell

I'm using `TeXLive 2014` on `MacOS X 10.6` and I'm currently working with `Aquamacs 2.5`.

I'm currently using two different shell scripts for compiling my `LaTeX` document (thesis), which are located in `~/bin/script1.sh` and `~/bin/script2.sh`

- At the moment I always switch to the terminal application for compiling and launch one of those commands there.
- I'd **like to define a custom keybinding** in `Emacs` which lets me run those scripts directly without leaving Emacs.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please do some background research before posting.  A quick google search for ["auctex custom compile command"](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=auctex+custom+compile+command) yields TeX.SE threads on ["How to change AUCTeX latex compile command?"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63736/how-to-change-auctex-latex-compile-command-using-emacs-23) and ["How to replace AUCTeX's “LaTeX” command..."](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163670/how-to-replace-auctexs-latex-command-with-latex-dvips-ps2pdf-chain).

Comment: Here is a link to an example with some fancy creation of variables -- e.g., `"%(latexmkrc-osx)` -- used in a custom compile command in AUCTeX:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156617/26911

Answer (score 1):

I assume you call your compile scripts like this:

```
~/bin/script1.bash master.tex
```

and that you only has to call it once. In this case here's a defun which does it:

```
(defun tex-custom-compile (arg)
  (interactive "P")
  "Calls `~/bin/script1.sh' on file associated with current buffer.
With C-u calls `~/bin/script2.sh' instead"
  (let (script texFile)

    (cond
     ((equal arg '(4))
      (setq script "~/bin/script2.sh ")
     )
     (t
      (setq script "~/bin/script1.sh ")
     )
    )

    (async-shell-command 
     (concat
      script
      (buffer-file-name)
     )
    )
  )
)
```

This defun should be easy to tweak to adjust it to your particular need. When you are satisfied with this defun bind it to a key:

```
(define-key TeX-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-t C-p") 'tex-custom-compile)
```

Comment: Could you edit your code to follow [elisp coding conventions](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Coding-Conventions.html) regarding close parentheses?

Comment: @Dan: I'd read the article you linked. For myself I use this style, because it allows me to comment a single line or a block: if I were to put multple closing parenthesis on the same line -- commenting won't work the simple way.

Comment: thanks for your help! No, I just call the script like I wrote (without any additional arguments yet, as it only compiles my thesis - THE ONE document ;-) ). And yes, I just call it once. One of the scripts just starts one pdflatex run and does some postprocessing/ document statistics, the other one starts latexmk (with several runs) and then the postprocessing/ document statistics.

Comment: @Martin: just comment `(buffer-file-name)` line and you done.